# Python - PyPdf2 merge does not keep PDF size

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a size issue when I merge a PDF using PyPDF2. I have the following code to merge pdfs files :

```
merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in fileSorted:
        merger.append(pdf[1])
        os.remove(pdf[1])
    merger.write(tmpPath + '/result.pdf')
```

The problem is, the PDF size is too high than the originals ones. How can I specify a pdf size ?

The input file has a size of 210*297mm (A4) and the ouptut has a size of 900x1273mm

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does the output look like? Size issues aside, is it appended correctly?

Comment: Yes I have no issue with the content, but the size is a problem for me because in a browser it's displaying badly (firefox pdf viewer zoom it instead of displaying fully the pdf)

Comment: That's really strange lol. All the files you're merging are the same size, 210*297, right?

Comment: I just post my solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. My problem was here because before merge I convert pdf to jpg and then convert jpg to pdf and then merge it. So I change the merge to this :

```
writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pdf in fileSorted:
   reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf[1])
   page   = PageObject.createBlankPage(reader)
   page.mergePage(reader.getPage(0))
   page.scaleTo(width=595,height=842)
   writer.addPage(page)


outputStream = open(tmpPath + '/result.pdf', 'wb')
writer.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```